# Stuck on a basic thinking question

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Stewart and Michael have arranged to meet. Michael is about to set off on his bicycle, and at the
same time Stewart is going to run to meet him.
Michael can cycle at a steady 20 kilometres per hour and Stewart can run at a steady 12 kilometres
per hour. They live 8 kilometres from each other.
How long will it be before they meet?

I have drawn out the situation but still am confused. This is from a thinking skills assessment so I don't think much mathematics is required.

Can I have a miniscule hint?

Thanks

Comment: How far apart would they live if it took them one hour to meet?

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry I fail to understand that.

Comment: They take same time to travel different distance, sum of both the distances is 8.

Comment: @Vikram can you explain how to get to the answer. I been stuck for a long time.

Comment: @salman: In 1 hour they would travel a combined $20+12$ kilometres.  But they only need travel a combined $8$ km, and this takes them ....

Answer (score 2):

If they go directly, they need to travel a *total* of $8$km. Thus
$$8 \text{km} = 20 \frac{\text{km}}{\text h} \cdot t + 12 \frac{\text{km}}{\text h} \cdot t = 32 \frac{\text{km}}{\text h} \cdot t$$
That makes $15$ minutes.

Comment: what is the scenario? At which point are Michal and stewart meeting at? I am picturing this in a confusing manner.

Comment: They meet $5$km away from Michael (or $3$km from Stewart)

Answer (score 1):

They are nearing each other at the combined speed of 32 km/h...

Answer (score 0):

Let $m$ be Michael's speed in $km/h$ and $s$ be Stewart's speed in $km/h$.  They are traveling towards each other, so their speeds combine in an additive way.  Taking $t$ as the time in hours, we have $t\cdot m+t\cdot s=8.$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: why are we adding the speeds together?

Comment: @salman: Galilean relativity

Comment: @Henry I haven't studied this. From a laymen perspective what is the approach

Comment: @salman: as I and others have said, "In 1 hour they would travel a combined 20+12 kilometres. But they only need travel a combined 8 km, and this takes them ...."

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let they meet at point C.  Micheal will take x/20 hr to reach C and Stewart will take (8-x)/12  hr to reach C.  Both started together and reached together on C, so, $\frac{x}{20}=\frac{8-x}{12}$ , which gives x=5, that means they will meet at 5 km from point A.  S0 they will meet after 1/4 hr OR 15 minutes.

Comment: Hello jee u use SUVAT

Comment: any problem with this method?

Comment: no my friend ask u is using SUVAT

Comment: I have used speed=(distance/time) only

Comment: why u cannat use suvats